# Tahoma Creek suspension bridge history

Tags: hiking, united-states, national-parks, history

One of my more memorable hiking experiences came on the [Wonderland Trail](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wonderland_Trail) in the summer of 1994. The trail is about 93 miles (150 kilometers) long. It's in the [Mount Rainier State Park](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Rainier_National_Park) which is located in the State of Washington in western United States.

The hike involved crossing Tahoma Creek on a completely decrepit foot bridge. At the time of my crossing, they were replacing the old bridge with this beautiful and structurally sound bridge:

[image]

I would like to know more about the history of the Tahoma Creek bridge (ideally with photos of the previous bridge).